# automatizar una tarea con autoit

Tags: script

Soy nuevo utilizando autoit, pero necesito automatizar una tarea con este programa.

necesito analizar una formula que ya esta en una celda en excel y si esa formula tiene una g remplazarla por una h

esta es la formula.

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO('Sct Desarrollo Economico'!$G$6:$G$29;"QUIMICO";'Sct 
 Desarrollo Economico'!$T$6:$T$29;"No aceptable o aceptable con control 
 especifico")
```

no se que codigo utilizar para decirle que me lea ese texto y si encuentra una g que lo cambia por una h.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar 1 expresion regular para localizar 1 caracter cualquiera dentro de 1 cadena (en este caso la letra g).

Busca StringRegExp en la ayuda de autoit y veras como solucionarlo.

Comment: Quizás sea más útil para el que preguntó si pudieras dar un ejemplo concreto (algo de código) dado que la pregunta fue concreta.